# Transaction Failed Issue:- Able to redirect to success page automatically(Hacked My Site)

Tags: magento-1.7, payment-methods, patches, security

Yesterday someone made attacked my site, he was able to produce order id without out any Transaction.

I have founded why this happened, but don't know how to resolve this critical issue.

**Here are the steps-**

1. Login to Your account.
2. Buy the item, it will redirect to the payment page.
3. select any bank with net banking option.
4. confirm the amount, it will ask for OTP, but don't put any OTP
5. You all need to found SUCCESS method of site,

once you will get that simply put URL into the browser it will redirect to success page in my case **www.mysite.com/checkout/onepage/success/**

At admin panel, I am getting Payment Completed message, but I have received Transaction fail mail from my merchant.

Also, I have installed all security patches given by Magento. and my Magento version is- 1.7.0.2.

Comment: Please Tell me some solution, i am still stuck

Comment: This seems to be a problem of your payment method rather than a hack. You should contact the extension vendor.